# How to generate a page depending on the ID received from a previous page (php/sql)

Tags: php, mysql, session

After being logged in my application, i have a list of items generated from my data base. Each one of them have a "read more" button. Once we click on it, we will be redirected on another page which present the 'full content' of the item clicked on.

My problem is : How to make sure that the 'right' session ID will lead to the right content ?

I have a while loop that upload the items in the application but when its all done, the session ID is stuck on the last item. which lead all my "read more" buttons to present the full content of that last one.

Thanks a lot guys !

(btw its my first question on stackoverflow ! Also, sorry if my English isn't that good..)

Edit :

i think that the problem is on my 'on click' function. There is the code :

```
while ($actorinfo = $req->fetch())
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = $actorinfo['id'];

    if (strlen($actorinfo['content']) > 100)
    {
        $extract = substr($actorinfo['content'], 0, 100)."...";
?>

<div class="actor">
    <div class="logo"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($actorinfo['logo']); ?></div>
    <h3 class="name"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($actorinfo['name']); ?></h3>
    <div class="content"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($extract); ?></div>
    <div class="read_more"><button class="button" onclick="window.location.href='pageActeur.php'">Lire la suite</button></div>
</div>

<?php
    }
}
$req->closeCursor();
?>
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without the code, but it seems as if you are generating the "read more" link at the wrong time if they all have the same id. It should be generated inside the loop rather than at the end - as you have seen, at the end all you will have is the last value.

Comment: Hi !  i edited the post with the code on the 'main page'. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Your "read more" button link doesn't include the `id` - you need to pass that in to `pageActeur.php` as a parameter, and have that code read it from the `$_GET` array instead of from the session. There's no point putting it into a session variable for what you are trying to do with it, really - if you insist on doing it via a session variable, you'll have to set one for each item returned in the loop, and then find some way of telling your PHP code which one you meant. Sticking it in the button link is far easier.

Comment: I ended up using a $_GET array as you suggested yes. Thanks a lot for your answers mate. Have a nice day !